# Merge Statement Performance Issue

Tags: query-optimization, oracle19c

I have merge statement with just update in it and it never executes just keep on running and running.
I have also separately execute the SRC query in it and seems like that query also never got executed there are only 2 tables involves in it.
Below are sample script with table structures, Merge Statement and explain Plan for it.

there are Wait events which got from Monitor Session for 3 runs (which never completes)

gc cr multi block mixed,
library cache pin,
pga memory operation

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB1 
   (    EFFECTIVE_DT DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CMPNY_CD VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CURRENCY VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    EXCHNG_RT NUMBER(28,13) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    LAST_CHNG TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) 
  TABLESPACE APP_TS ;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST_TAB1_IDX1 ON TEST_TAB1 (EFFECTIVE_DT, CMPNY_CD, CURRENCY)
  TABLESPACE APP_TS ;

ALTER TABLE TEST_TAB1 ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_TAB1_PK PRIMARY KEY (EFFECTIVE_DT, CMPNY_CD, CURRENCY)
  USING INDEX TEST_TAB1_IDX1  ENABLE;

  CREATE INDEX TEST_TAB1_IDX2 ON TEST_TAB1 (LAST_CHNG)
  TABLESPACE APP_TS ;

Row Count in TEST_TAB1 - 17369608
  
  CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB2 
   (    
    BUSINESS_DT DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,           
    ORG_CRCY VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
    ORG_CRCY_A NUMBER(23,3) NOT NULL ENABLE,     
    CMPNY_CD VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    FUNC_CRCY NUMBER(23,3) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) 
  TABLESPACE APP_TS ;

Row Count in TEST_TAB2 -- 300711

  
MERGE INTO TEST_TAB2 wk
              USING (
                             With temp_tab2 as (select distinct CMPNY_CD,ORG_CRCY ,BUSINESS_DT from TEST_TAB2 )
                             ,temp_tab1 as (select max(EFFECTIVE_DT) as EFFECTIVE_DT, g1.CMPNY_CD,g1.ORG_CRCY,g1.BUSINESS_DT, 0.0  EXCHNG_RT
                                             from temp_tab2 g1 inner join  TEST_TAB1 flx on g1.CMPNY_CD=flx.CMPNY_CD and g1.ORG_CRCY=flx.CURRENCY
                                             and flx.EFFECTIVE_DT < g1.BUSINESS_DT group by g1.CMPNY_CD,g1.ORG_CRCY,g1.BUSINESS_DT)
                             ,temp_tab1Final as ( select t1.EFFECTIVE_DT, t1.CMPNY_CD,t1.ORG_CRCY,t1.BUSINESS_DT,
                                case when flx.CURRENCY  is not null then flx.EXCHNG_RT else t1.EXCHNG_RT end rate
                                from temp_tab1 t1 left join TEST_TAB1 flx
                                on  t1.CMPNY_CD=flx.CMPNY_CD and t1.ORG_CRCY=flx.CURRENCY and t1.EFFECTIVE_DT=flx.EFFECTIVE_DT
                                )select * from temp_tab1Final
                    )src ON ( wk.CMPNY_CD=src.CMPNY_CD and src.ORG_CRCY =wk.ORG_CRCY )
              WHEN MATCHED  THEN
              UPDATE  SET FUNC_CRCY = src.rate * wk.ORG_CRCY_A;               
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                |                                   |     1 |    39 |  2132   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE                         | TEST_TAB2                         |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |                                   |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                                   |     1 |   266 |  2132   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                  |                                   |     1 |   242 |  2130   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TEST_TAB2                         |     1 |   216 |   307   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      VIEW                      |                                   |     1 |    26 |  1823   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       SORT GROUP BY            |                                   |     1 |    31 |  1823   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        NESTED LOOPS            |                                   |     1 |    31 |  1822   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TEST_TAB2                         |     1 |    15 |   307   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN       | TEST_TAB1_IDX1                    |    48 |   768 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_TAB1                         |     1 |    24 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | TEST_TAB1_IDX1                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - access("WK"."CMPNY_CD"="T1"."CMPNY_CD" AND "T1"."ORG_CRCY"="WK"."ORG_CRCY")
  10 - access("CMPNY_CD"="FLX"."CMPNY_CD" AND "ORG_CRCY"="FLX"."CURRENCY" AND "FLX"."EFFECTIVE_DT"<"BUSINESS_DT")
       filter("ORG_CRCY"="FLX"."CURRENCY" AND "CMPNY_CD"="FLX"."CMPNY_CD")
  12 - access("T1"."EFFECTIVE_DT"="FLX"."EFFECTIVE_DT"(+) AND "T1"."CMPNY_CD"="FLX"."CMPNY_CD"(+) AND 
              "T1"."ORG_CRCY"="FLX"."CURRENCY"(+))            

Oracle version -- Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Please If you see any scope to Tune it please let me know I will Try.

****EDIT SAMPLE DATA ****

```
Insert into TEST_TAB1 (EFFECTIVE_DT,CMPNY_CD,CURRENCY,EXCHNG_RT,LAST_CHNG) values (to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'XYZ','USD',1.328991959599,to_timestamp('22-JAN-15 01.19.38.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into TEST_TAB1 (EFFECTIVE_DT,CMPNY_CD,CURRENCY,EXCHNG_RT,LAST_CHNG) values (to_date('25-FEB-22','DD-MON-RR'),'XYZ','USD',1.331292018904,to_timestamp('22-JAN-15 01.19.38.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into TEST_TAB1 (EFFECTIVE_DT,CMPNY_CD,CURRENCY,EXCHNG_RT,LAST_CHNG) values (to_date('21-JUL-05','DD-MON-RR'),'XYZ','USD',1.31743626902,to_timestamp('22-JAN-15 01.19.38.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into TEST_TAB1 (EFFECTIVE_DT,CMPNY_CD,CURRENCY,EXCHNG_RT,LAST_CHNG) values (to_date('22-JUL-05','DD-MON-RR'),'XYZ','USD',1.306421059507,to_timestamp('22-JAN-15 01.19.38.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
              
              

Insert into TEST_TAB2 (BUSINESS_DT,ORG_CRCY,ORG_CRCY_A,CMPNY_CD,FUNC_CRCY) values (to_date('28-FEB-22','DD-MON-RR'),'USD',50979531.06,'XYZ',0);
Insert into TEST_TAB2 (BUSINESS_DT,ORG_CRCY,ORG_CRCY_A,CMPNY_CD,FUNC_CRCY) values (to_date('28-FEB-22','DD-MON-RR'),'USD',1663875,'XYZ',0);
Insert into TEST_TAB2 (BUSINESS_DT,ORG_CRCY,ORG_CRCY_A,CMPNY_CD,FUNC_CRCY) values (to_date('28-FEB-22','DD-MON-RR'),'USD',-17354778.41,'XYZ',0);
Insert into TEST_TAB2 (BUSINESS_DT,ORG_CRCY,ORG_CRCY_A,CMPNY_CD,FUNC_CRCY) values (to_date('28-FEB-22','DD-MON-RR'),'USD',17216450,'XYZ',0);
```

***Soultion***

Changed Query (60 seconds taken for Merge with TAB1 = 17M and TAB2 = 300K records) --

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TAB2 wk USING (
select t2.CMPNY_CD,t2.org_crcy,t2.business_dt
,max(EXCHNG_RT) keep (dense_rank last order by effective_dt) rate
from TEST_TAB1 t1
join test_tab2 t2 on t1.cmpny_cd = t2.cmpny_cd and t1.currency = t2.org_crcy and t2.business_dt > t1.effective_dt
group by t2.CMPNY_CD,t2.org_crcy,t2.business_dt
) src ON ( wk.CMPNY_CD=src.CMPNY_CD and wk.org_crcy = src.org_crcy and wk.business_dt = src.business_dt)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET FUNC_CRCY = src.rate * wk.ORG_CRCY_A;
```

New Index on TEST_TAB2 table --

```
CREATE  INDEX TEST_TAB2_IDX1 ON TEST_TAB2 (CMPNY_CD,Org_CrcyC,BUSINESS_DT)
 TABLESPACE APP_TS ;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add in sample data for your tables.

Comment: I have added sample data in question

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your merge statement's logic, I think you can cut out one set of joins by using the `max()` analytic function, something like:

```
MERGE INTO test_tab2 tgt
USING (WITH      temp_tab2 AS (SELECT disinct cmpny_cd, org_crcy, business_dt FROM test_tab2),
            temp_tab_final AS (SELECT tt2.cmpny_cd,
                                      tt2.org_crcy,
                                      tt2.business_dt,
                                      t1.effective_dt,
                                      MAX(t1.effective_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY tt2.cmpny_cd, tt2.org_crcy, tt2.business_dt) max_effective_dt
                                      COALESCE(t1.exchng_rt, 0) exchng_rt
                               FROM   temp_tab2 tt2
                                      INNER JOIN test_tab1 t1 ON tt2.cmpny_cd = t1.cmpny_cd
                                                                 AND tt2.org_crcy = t1.currency
                                                                 AND tt2.business_date > t1.effective_dt)
       SELECT cmpny_cd,
              org_crcy,
              business_dt,
              effective_dt,
              exchng_rt
       FROM   temp_tab_final
       WHERE  effective_dt = max_effective_dt) src
  ON (tgt.cmpny_cd = src.cmpny_cd AND src.org_crcy = tgt.org_crcy) -- should "and tgt.business_dt = src.business_dt" be in the join conditions?
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.func_crcy = tgt.org_crcy_a * src.exchng_rt;
```

Whether that is more efficient than your original query, I don't know. You'd need to test for yourself. Perhaps adding another index to test_tab1 on cmpny_cd, currency, effective_dt, exchng_rt would help speed things up even further (it would do away with the need for the table look-ups, since all the info would be in the index).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, I will try to use your suggestion for Index I am not sure I will be provided approval for that as TAB1 could be used in other process as well so index might hamper there performance so need to do a regression test in this case. 
Also I am also trying with WINDOWING function as well at my end but No Luck as of now :(

Comment: Have you gathered statistics on your tables?

Comment: Also, it looks like there aren't any indexes or constraints on test_tab2; is that correct? Adding indexes there should help a great deal. And I think you're missing a join condition on your merge statement - shouldn't the rows in test_tab2 be joined on the business_date to the source query?

Comment: No Gather Stats is also there but not sure why I am just forgetting it.
Yeah I Talked with my teammate he said first look for ways without creating indexes

Comment: Do not have privilege to gather stats :(
Weird